# Event handling in Autobahn Python

Tags: python, websocket, autobahn

I want my websocket client to close connection as soon as my_flag is set to True.
Here's my socket class:

```
class BridgeSocket(WebSocketClientProtocol):
    def __init__(self,factory,my_flag):
        self.my_flag = my_flag
```

Now, my_flag is set as true after some time somewhere else in the program run.(inside a different thread). Instead of waiting in a

```
while True:
    sleep(1)
```

kind of loop, is there any event which I can define and attach to my websocket class. 
i.e. a function which gets fired when my_flag is set to true

Answer (score 0):

Use [threading.Event](http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#event-objects).

```
# initialization code
self.my_event = threading.Event()

# sct.my_event.set() is called from somewhere

# waiting code, to replace while True:...
sct.my_event.wait()
```

Comment: I am not able to understand your solution. My class is deriving from WebSocketClientProtocol. How will I use threading events in that? Could you please explain in detail.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should spawn your background task using Twisted `deferToThread` and then notify the WebSocket stuff running on the main thread using `callFromThread`.